# Variable declared but not used, but it IS used in the same func?

Tags: go

i am new to Go, coming from Python. I have the variables declared, but Go tells me that they aren't. I don't get the reason :/

```
.\logcollector.go:61:3: vonP declared but not used
.\logcollector.go:69:3: bisP declared but not used
```

Here's a code snippet:

```
if isFlagPassed("von") {
    vonP, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", *vonPtr)
    if err != nil {
        vonP, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, "1970-01-01")
        fmt.Println("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Von-Datum auf " + vonP.String() + " gesetzt.")
    }
}
```

and a little bit lower:

```
fmt.PrintLn(vonP)
fmt.PrintLn(bisP)
```

So both of them GET used.

Comment: The first `vonP` (which should correspond to the line in the error message) is not used  the compiler error is correct.

Comment: why is the first and the 2nd vonP different, i still don't understand it?

Comment: The application uses short variable declarations to declare  `vonP` variables inside the scope of the if statements.  Both variables are unused.  Fix by using assignment instead of short variable declarations.

Comment: So, there is a variable scope inside of ifs if i understand you correclty? Do you have a link to read that up?

Comment: @Faulander Oops, the second `vonP` is used. I missed the use at the end of the long line. See  [scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope), [short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), [assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments).

Comment: And also in [Effective Go: redeclaration](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#redeclaration)

Comment: ah, i get it now. ":=" is a shortcut for a declaration and there is no error if the variable is been declared before, pretty smart!

Comment: one more question: vonP is already declared, err is not. So vonP, err = time.Parse will result in an error. can i declare only err in this case?

Comment: @Faulander: read that again (or test out some other combinations), it is an error if there are only variables which have previously been declared within the same scope. https://play.golang.org/p/yBZg9ib9r8n

Answer (score 1):

```golang
vonP, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", *vonPtr)
```

You are use `vonP` only at this line. Second usage inside of `if` - is another variable.

In your case line above must looks something like

```golang
_, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", *vonPtr)
```

If you are need to use one variable twice, try something like this

```golang
if isFlagPassed("von") {
    vonP, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", *vonPtr)
    if err != nil {
        vonP, _ = time.Parse(layoutISO, "1970-01-01") // = instead of :=
        fmt.Println("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Von-Datum auf " + vonP.String() + " gesetzt.")
    }
}
```

Comment: so how do i get GO do not use another variable inside the if block but the one outside? I already tried delcaring them globally, but it didn't work either.

Comment: you can remove the initializer operator from the second assignment inside the if statement.such that it becomes vonP, _ = time.Parse(layoutISO, "1970-01-01")